# cannot match using the match function and provides NA error

Tags: r

Could able to replace the corresponding values using match function provides error as
 `NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments` Please help me in getting the expected output.

```
as1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,6),
                  pID = c(21,22,23,26),
                  Values = c(435,33,45,12))

as2 <- data.frame(Values_a = c(435, 676),
                  Values_b = c(544, 676))

as1$Values[match(as2$Values_a, as1$Values)] <- as2$Values_b


Error in as1$Values[match(as2$Values_a, as1$Values)] <- as2$Values_b : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

Expected result

```
  ID pID Values
1  1  21    544
2  2  22     33
3  3  23     45
4  6  26     12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `match` 676 with `Values` it returns `NA` and you cannot subset that as an index from `as1$Values`. If you want to use `match` try :

```
inds <- !is.na(match(as2$Values_a, as1$Values))
as1$Values[inds] <- as2$Values_b[inds]
```

---

You could also join the data :

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(as1, as2, by = c('Values' = 'Values_a')) %>%
  mutate(Values = coalesce(Values_b, Values)) %>%
  select(names(as1))

#  ID pID Values
#1  1  21    544
#2  2  22     33
#3  3  23     45
#4  6  26     12
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `nomatch` argument in `match`.  By default, it is `NA`.  We can change it to 0 and this should work as in `R`, indexing starts from 1 and not 0

```
inds <- match(as2$Values_a, as1$Values, nomatch = 0)
as1$Values[inds] <- as2$Values_b[inds]
```

-output

```
as1
#  ID pID Values
#1  1  21    544
#2  2  22     33
#3  3  23     45
#4  6  26     12
```

NOTE: Wrapping `!is.na` around `match` and using that as indexing can results incorrect output as it is based on logical values as the info from the `match` index is not used.  It can result in assignment based on a different order of values